# Ancient words on back of vigraha in Devanagari

Tags: idols

[image]

This maybe the back of a Jain tirthankar idol. What language are the words?

Comment: While i don't see why this isn't a history question, it happens not to be the kind we can usually answer, so I've suggested that Hinduism or linguistics stack should have it